# Django API and Portal - Serving from using CNAME and diferent apps

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-views

I am building and application that will have a Portal for our customers. Besides that thye could consume information using an API. I would like to serve the Portal in the root domain, and the api using a CNAME like api.domain.com. SO basically I have two questions:

Is it a best practice to have two apps: one for the api and other to server the portal?

How could i route the CNAME ( api.domain.com) in my `settings.py` file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are describing is splitting the frontend and backend into two different applications - yes this is a standard practice.

Using the same Django application for the two "different" applications is non-standard. You could try writing your own solution for checking the origin of a request and rerouting/blocking requests depending on the source.

On another note, I always have a simple portal on my django api backend application which typically includes an interactive docs portal (swagger/redoc) and the built in django admin pages.

Comment: "I always have a simple portal on my django api backend application which typically includes an interactive docs portal (swagger/redoc) and the built in django admin pages." that's what I am planing to do. When i said portal, it means the admin portal  :)

Comment: For the front-end app, you could use any framework and consumes the api's generated by the django rest framework?

Comment: Correct, I prefer React.js - but one could also use, for example, another python client to connect to the APIs - you'll need to be wary of CORS and ensure others can access your API if you woould like it to be public - django has some easy to use CORS 3rd party packages to make setting this up easy